# Modifying Gcode mid-print in response to sensor feedback for concept printer

Tags: c++, arduino, g-code, 3d-printing

I'm developing a concept printer that burns images onto wood using a magnifying glass on an xy plotter. One of my anticipated challenges is an inconsistent print quality as a result of changing lighting conditions (e.g., atmosphere, clouds).

My plan is to modify my Gcode on-the-fly, (yes, while printing) based on the feedback from photosensors in order to maintain a consistent burn. Modifying my feedrate to accommodate changes in lighting conditions seems like the simplest approach.

What I can't find is how to modify Gcode AFTER a print has begun.

ideas?

Comment: What GCODE engine will you use?  That will largely determine the latest time you can alter the feed rate.

Answer (score 0):

CNC machines use ladder logic to change machine parameters while running a program. They never change the code they are running. You need your program to be static and reproducible. You need to be able to version control your code. Editing the code live will most certainly lead to disaster.

You don't need to change the code to change the feed rate. Usually there is a dial to control feedrate. This can be locked out in software and controlled based on sensors.

Your question is lacking the information for a more specific answer. We would need to know what machine and control software you are using.